# How to allow top-level JSON array param in Ruby Grape

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I have a route with /coordinates. I want to receive a JSON Array on this route, such as:

```
[
    {"latitude": 1, "longitude": 1},
    {"latitude": 1, "longitude": 2},
    {"latitude": 1, "longitude": 3}
]
```

How do I configure the params to parse this kind of data with grape? I don't want to give a name to the array such as `{ "blah": []}`, I just want to read it from the request.

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
params do
  requires :latitude, type: Float
  requires :longitude, type: Float
end
post do
  route = Route.create(coordinates: params)
  { id: route.id }
end
```

Comment: You mean the entire request's body will be a JSON?

Comment: This is an area where grape I think has a shortcoming.  I looked into it a while back and didn't come up with a satisfactory answer ("how do you declare a top-level nameless parameter") but am looking again.

Comment: So... this is not currently easy to do without rolling it yourself by parsing the overall payload.  See: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/1730